# AngularJS: Unable to display Variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new into Angular. In my JS file I did following:

```
App.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', 'ProductService', function ($scope,ProductService) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('startX');
    $scope.price = '$55.6';
}]);
```

IN view I am doing this:

```
<div class="bloc-bleu">
   <div class="f" ng-controller="ProductController">
     <p><span>{{ price }}</span><!--  au lieu de <span class="old price">1250€</span> --></p>
```

But I am unable to get value of `price` in view.

**Update**: I can see this error in console:

[image]

Comment: what are you getting? why dont u set us a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/67/) with your code?

Comment: well, with the information that you have provided it is really hard to tell. If you could provide fiddle just like @adolfosrs said, we could be of some help.

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked Question updated

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to instantiate your module and to add `ng-app` in your html file.

Here's a `snippet` working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ProductController', function ($scope) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('startX');
    $scope.price = '$55.6';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="bloc-bleu">
     <div class="f" ng-controller="ProductController">
       <p><span>{{ price }}</span><!--  au lieu de <span class="old price">1250€</span> --></p>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's there: `<body ng-app="app">`

Comment: You didn't instantiate your module, take a look at my answer carefully.

Comment: As I  mentioned; it's initialized and also directive mentioned in HTML

Comment: Well, it wasn't mentioned in your question and as you can see, it's working in the snippet above.

Comment: `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'angularMoment', 'ngAnimate']);`

Comment: @Volatil3, can you edit your question with your complete code? This way it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115469/discussion-between-developer033-and-volatil3).

Comment: Question is now updted

Comment: Hard to tell something without the complete code.. but I can bet your problem is with datePicker, as the console says. You must post the complete code to get more specific help.